# Understanding proxy settings in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, proxy, ubuntu-12.04

I'm behind a university proxy and I'm very confused about Ubuntu's proxy settings and I'd love if someone can clarify it for me.

If I look inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf` it has my custom set proxy as

```
Acquire::http{Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy:port";};
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@proxy:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:pass@proxy:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:pass@proxy:port/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://user:pass@proxy:port/";
```

Inside `/etc/environment` I have

```
http_proxy="http://proxy:port/"
https_proxy="https://proxy:port/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://proxy:port/"
socks_proxy="socks://proxy:port/"
```

But if I do this `echo $http_proxy` then I get

```
http://differentproxy:differentport
```

I don't get it from where it's 'echo'ing. Any clarification? I know I can export the $http_proxy variable to the correct proxy but I just want to understand which program/process etc use which settings because apparently there are 3 different settings files. Might even be more.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/environment is where export goes, so just add it there. There's a lot of relevant questions on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) about this. ie, https://askubuntu.com/q/158557/89202

> Edit your:
>
> `gedit /etc/bash.bashrc`
>
> Enter the details in this format.
>
> `export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/`
>
> `export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/`

Comment: I tested that by doing `export http_proxy=10.1.1.1:9090`, but my `/etc/environment` still has the old proxy.